# Stop all on delete cascading in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, cascade

Trying to wrap my head around the following problem:

I have three classes, `A`, `AB` and `B`, as so:

```
class AB(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'), nullable=False)
    a = relationship(
        'A', 
        cascade='save-update', 
        backref=backref(
            'abs', 
            cascade='save-update', 
            uselist=True
        )
    )
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.id'), nullable=False)
    b = relationship(
        'B', 
        cascade='save-update', 
        backref=backref(
            'abs', 
            cascade='save-update', 
            uselist=True
        )
    )
    __tablename__ = 'ab'

class A(Base)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __tablename__ = 'a'

class B(Base)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    __tablename__ = 'b'
```

Essentially, this is a m2m relationship between `A` and `B`. The only non-standard thing is that there is a column `id` in the table `AB`. It's there for a reason.

I want to implement "merging" of two instances of `A`. We are given `a1` and `a2`. Then, before deleting `a1`, all of its relationships with `AB`s should be reassigned to `a2`. It is vitally important to retain the values of `AB.id` in the process (hence, no new instances of `AB` should actually be created or deleted).

**THE PROBLEM** No matter how I try, every time I delete an instance of `A`, SQLAlchemy attempts to update the foreign_key with a `NULL` value, consequently breaking the `NOT NULL` constraint. It does that by issuing an explicit `UPDATE ab SET a_id = NULL WHERE id = ...`. It does so, even though I have the following loop in my program:

```
for ab in a1.abs:
    ab.a_id = a2.id
    session.db.add(ab)

session.db.delete(a1)
```

Therefore it would seem to me that before delete is issued, all the `ab`s related to `a1` were safely moved to `a2`, however something is wrong.

**SOME NON-SOLUTIONS**

- The `passive_deletes` flag. The difference in behaviour concerns only those rows that aren't already in the memory which is not good.
- Adding a `delete` cascade is very risky for me. I want to really make sure that no `ab` objects are lost in the process of merging.
- Updating the lists kept in the associations manually, doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever (The `UPDATE` is issued again).

Would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: simple curiosity, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes, actually just a few hours ago. As it turns out SQLAlchemy doesn't seem to handle well manual updates to objects present in relationships. Either change your data using relationships API only; or don't rely on relationships at all when performing an update.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are problems with synchronisation between the contents of the relationships and the actual set of rows in the database, I recommend using `session.expire()`. It forces values being reloaded from the DB the next time data is accessed.

About expire & refresh:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#refreshing-expiring

About stale data in collections:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#deleting-from-collections

These functions saved my life. Now, everything works as expected. Moreover, I can do bulk updates via `sqlalchemy.sql.expression` API which is generally much faster without sacrificing data integrity in the ORM layer.

Comment: ahhhm... I see. I've never used sqlalchemy yet, but it is good to know... +1!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... something is very wrong here.

"UPDATE ab SET a_id = NULL WHERE id = a1.id" should affect 0 rows since you have already updated all ab where ab.a_id = a1.id.

Therefore only one possible explanation, you have failed to update ab. Computers tend not to lie. We only miss their logic sometimes.

My solution: to make sure everyhting is ok, before issuing the delete, find all rows of ab that point to a1.id if as it is to be expected, you find at least one, try to understand why that row is still there.

maybe session.db.add(ab) can be replaced by somehting like session.db.update(ab) and the add() is adding new rows to your ab table, or if no update exist or you can't use it, then delete first all ab where ab.a_id = a1.id after making sure you have correctly made copies (which I think you have)